# 0x quote request failing code 105

Tags: 0x

any time I submit a quote request to the 0x API with the taker address specified I get the following message:

```
{"code":105,"reason":"SenderNotAuthorizedError","values":{"sender":"**0x API Contract Address**"}}
```

Not sure if this has to do with setting a token allowance but I'm not sure why I would as it's my understanding that would come later in the process of sending.

Also, if I specifically set WETH as the sellToken, the error message will change but ONLY when a reletively large amount such as 1 WETH. At that point the message is the following:

```
{"code":111,"reason":"Gas estimation failed"}
```

I've tried testing this on both the main network and the ropsten test network.

Comment: Sorry the "taker address" is actually the 0x API's contract address.

Comment: Can you add in your question an example where this happens? To me inspect

Answer (score 0):

If the takerAddress is included in the quote fetch, the approval for token allowance should already be met for the respective Zero Ex Exchange Proxy Address.